# Code coverage help for Salesforce controller for VF page?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I have a controller that is showing 0% code coverage, but I'm not sure why my test class isn't covering anything.  Can anyone help?

Here is my controller:

```html
public class R2MBizBookController{

    public List<Buyer__c> listOfDeck {get; set;}
    public List<Buyer__c> listOfNewThirty {get; set;}
    public List<Buyer__c> listOfNewTW {get; set;}
    public List<Buyer__c> listOfLegacy {get; set;}
    public List<Buyer__c> listOfTQ {get; set;}
    public List<Buyer__c> listOfAQ {get; set;}
    public List<Buyer__c> listOfBQ {get; set;}
    public List<Buyer__c> listOfCQ {get; set;}
    public List<Buyer__c> listOfDQ {get; set;}
    public List<Buyer__c> listOfEQ {get; set;}
    public Buyer__c Live {get; set;}
    public Buyer__c NewTW {get; set;}
    public Buyer__c Viability {get; set;}
    public Buyer__c LaunchPad {get; set;}
    public Buyer__c TQ {get; set;}
    public Buyer__c AQ {get; set;}
    public Buyer__c BQ {get; set;}
    public Buyer__c CQ {get; set;}
    public Buyer__c DQ {get; set;}
    public Buyer__c EQ {get; set;}
   
public R2MBizBookController() {
    listofDeck = [Select id, name, Sales_Lead_Source__c, Routing_Status__c, Client_Status__c, Total_Re_Orders__c, Sales_Quarter__c, Funds_Collected_All_Time__c, Sales_LN__c, Commitment_c__c from Buyer__c WHERE Pipeline_Status__c = 'OnDeck' ORDER BY Name ASC];
    listofNewThirty = [Select id, name, Sales_Lead_Source__c, Routing_Status__c, Client_Status__c, Total_Re_Orders__c, Sales_Quarter__c, Funds_Collected_All_Time__c, Sales_LN__c, Sales_Origination_Date__c from Buyer__c WHERE Pipeline_Status__c = 'New 30' ORDER BY Sales_Origination_Date__c DESC];
    listofNewTW = [Select id, name, Sales_Lead_Source__c, Routing_Status__c, Client_Status__c, Total_Re_Orders__c, Sales_Quarter__c, Funds_Collected_All_Time__c, Sales_LN__c, Sales_Origination_Date__c from Buyer__c WHERE  New_Live__c = TRUE  ORDER BY Sales_Origination_Date__c DESC];
    listofLegacy = [Select id, name, Sales_Lead_Source__c, Routing_Status__c, Client_Status__c, Total_Re_Orders__c, Sales_Quarter__c, Funds_Collected_All_Time__c, Sales_LN__c, Sales_Origination_Date__c from Buyer__c WHERE Pipeline_Status__c = 'Legacy' ORDER BY  Sales_Origination_Date__c DESC];
    listofTQ = [Select id, name, Sales_Lead_Source__c, Routing_Status__c, Client_Status__c, Total_Re_Orders__c, Sales_Quarter__c, Funds_Collected_All_Time__c, Sales_LN__c, Sales_Origination_Date__c from Buyer__c WHERE TQ_Pipeline__c = TRUE ORDER BY  Sales_Origination_Date__c DESC];
    listofAQ = [Select id, name, Sales_Lead_Source__c, Routing_Status__c, Client_Status__c, Total_Re_Orders__c, Sales_Quarter__c, Funds_Collected_All_Time__c, Sales_LN__c, Sales_Origination_Date__c from Buyer__c WHERE Pipeline_Status__c = 'AQ' ORDER BY  Sales_Origination_Date__c DESC];
    listofBQ = [Select id, name, Sales_Lead_Source__c, Routing_Status__c, Client_Status__c, Total_Re_Orders__c, Sales_Quarter__c, Funds_Collected_All_Time__c, Sales_LN__c, Sales_Origination_Date__c from Buyer__c WHERE Pipeline_Status__c = 'BQ' ORDER BY  Sales_Origination_Date__c DESC];
    listofCQ = [Select id, name, Sales_Lead_Source__c, Routing_Status__c, Client_Status__c, Total_Re_Orders__c, Sales_Quarter__c, Funds_Collected_All_Time__c, Sales_LN__c, Sales_Origination_Date__c from Buyer__c WHERE Pipeline_Status__c = 'CQ' ORDER BY  Sales_Origination_Date__c DESC];
    listofDQ = [Select id, name, Sales_Lead_Source__c, Routing_Status__c, Client_Status__c, Total_Re_Orders__c, Sales_Quarter__c, Funds_Collected_All_Time__c, Sales_LN__c, Sales_Origination_Date__c from Buyer__c WHERE Pipeline_Status__c = 'DQ' ORDER BY  Sales_Origination_Date__c DESC];
    listofEQ = [Select id, name, Sales_Lead_Source__c, Routing_Status__c, Client_Status__c, Total_Re_Orders__c, Sales_Quarter__c, Funds_Collected_All_Time__c, Sales_LN__c, Sales_Origination_Date__c from Buyer__c WHERE Pipeline_Status__c = 'EQ' ORDER BY  Sales_Origination_Date__c DESC];
   


}
}
```

and here is my test class:

```html
@isTest(seeAllData =  true)
public class R2MBizBookControllerTest{
    // Unit test Method
    static testmethod void UnitTest() {
        //Create your buyer record with required field
        //Buyer__c b = new Buyer__c(Pipeline_Status__c = 'Legacy');
        //insert b;
        test.startTest();
           R2MBizBookController ub = new R2MBizBookController();
        test.stopTest();
    }   
}
```

would anyone be willing to help me beef this up?

it would mean the world to me.

thank you in advance!!!!!!

John

Answer (score 0):

There are several best practices that you are breaking in your code.  However, without knowing what this is being used for, it's hard to provide you with fixes.

As it's written, your test class should be providing 66% coverage of your controller not 0%.  You need an average of 75% across all Triggers and Classes.  You need to provide coverage for the 10 Buyer__c variables in your controller.

Also, be sure to deploy to production your Test Class with your Controller.